# has_many (different objects) as: one type of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I need a way of referrencing 2 different objects as 1.

I have a Message object with needs to keep track of Recipients.  the problem is that Recipients could be a User or a Contact.

should the models be:   ?

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, as: :recipients
  has_many :contacts, as: :recipients
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
end
```

because, I feel like polymorphic relationships are built to go the opposite way.

also, this way doesn't allow me to reference @message.recipients which is what I need.

I hope this makes sense
Thank you

Comment: What are Contact and User? Two different Active Record Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is completely incorrect. I think you need many-to-many association. My association whould be that:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipient_links
  has_many :users, through: :recipient_links, source: :recipient, source_type: 'User'
  has_many :contacts, through: :recipient_links, source: :recipient, source_type: 'Contact'
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipient_links, as: :recipient
  has_many :messages, through: :recipient_links
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipient_links, as: :recipient
  has_many :messages, through: :recipient_links
end

# fields: message_id, recipient_id, recipient_type
class RecipientLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :message
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing something just like this :)

Answer (score 0):

... I can't add comments yet so i give here solution for: When use answer from up to receive all @message.recipients every type in only 2 request:

```
RecipientLink.includes(:recipient).where(message_id: @message.id).collect(&:recipient)
```